# Change buttons dynamically using responseData index and length - React autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, button, dynamic, autocomplete

When search operation is performed, my page lists different itemNumbers with 'Remove' button next to it. The very last row of the list will by default have autocomplete box enabled to add a new item (itemNumber) with 'Add' button instead of 'Remove' button. If a new item is added using that row, the button automatically changes to 'Remove', and a new row is added below again with 'Add' button.

```js
render(){
    const currentItem = Object.values(this.state.currentItem);
    const CurrentItemToRender = this.state.currentItem.filter((ca) => ca.item);
    const numRows = CurrentItemToRender.length;
```

Sets selected item from autocomplete dropdown to the state. I tried incrementing numRows by 1 if value is null as that could solve my problem but its not getting reflected when rendered (please see render() code above).

```
onChangeCaptureItem = i => (event, value) => {     
    let CurrentItemToRender = this.state.currentItem.filter((ca) => ca. itemNo);
    let numRows = CurrentItemToRender.length;
    let currentItem = [...this.state.currentItem];
    if (value === null) {
        numRows = numRows + 1     
    }
    else {
        currentItem[i].itemNo = value;
    }
    this.setState({ currentItem });
}
```

Method that returns the list of itemNumbers

```
searchItem() {
    getItem(this.state.currentItem [0].parentItemNo).then(
        (response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                response.json()
                    .then((responseData) => {
                        let lengthOfResponse = Object.keys(responseData).length
                        this.removeAllFields(0); 
                        for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfResponse; i++) {
                            this.addFormFields();
                            let currentItem = [...this.state.currentItem];
                            currentItem[i].itemNo = responseData[i];
                            if (this.state.currentItem[i].itemNo == this.state.currentItem[i].parentItemNo) {
                                this.removeRow(i); 
                            }
                            this.setState({ currentItem });
                            this.setState({ searchMode: true });
                            this.setState({ addRow: true })
                        }
                        this.addFormFields(); // adds the last row with Add button
                    })
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that is happening for the `key`. You are using index as your key. Which is not a good approach. Use any unique identifier instead. You can read more [here](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/)

You can do something like this

```
<div className="form-inline" key={index+element.itemNo}>
```

Assuming `element.itemNo` is a unique identifier

Comment: 'element.itemNo' is unique 8 to 10 digit string which s a combination of numbers and alphabets. Will the above mentioned idea still work ? . If yes,  should key be used in place of index like 'key+ 1 < numRows '

Comment: Yes it will work. No you can't write like key+1<numRows. Both situations are different. Here in the logic index using as a counter but here index is a unique identifier.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how do we go about it. I need to compare the key with numRows to decide which button(Remove or Add) to be displayed. But that comparison wouldn't work as expected if I use element.itemNo.

Comment: I think if you update the specific part that I mentioned is enough. Because the logic with numRows is fine.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding key={index+element.itemNo}. But still same problem exists. Last but one row becomes 'Add', when i remove entered data (by clicking 'x' in autocomplete box) from last row.

Comment: What is your logic of the last button?

Comment: I have added logic for your reference

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You want to show the last row button remove button right?

Comment: No, Last row button is 'Add',. Because only last row is for adding new item. Whereas all other rows have 'Remove' as they are retrieved from database. Which works well as per my code. Only problem is when a value (itemNumber ) is added to the last row and decide to undo that by clicking 'X' ('X' in autocomplete box) or removing that data, the previous row button changes to 'Add' (which is not expected, should stay as 'Remove'). I want the last but one row button to stay 'Remove'.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Is the problem still existing?

Comment: Yes, could not figure why 'numRows' value changes when entered value is undone(database is not involved here, just the UI)  by pressing 'X' in autocomplete.

Comment: That can only happen if your ```currentItem``` state is changed. The code you gave in description has no dependency to update it. I think the onChnage function of autocompelte is doing that

Comment: Thank you, You are correct. 'numRows' gets decremented because of state change. I tried incrementing numRows on onChange if value is null but couldn't get it to work as it does not reflect during render. Added some code for reference.

Comment: I think it's complex to find the mistake. Please create a codesandbos and share the link here. You edited the old description

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Sorry man. I was too much busy this week. Didn't get a chance to take a look at that